# Angular 2 - Create a side menu that the user can navigate in, without changing the URL, until a route is selected

Tags: angular

I want to create a menu, that when the user clicks on specific elements inside the menu, the menu just continues until he clicks an element that changes the route of the application. Is this possible in Angular 2? And if so, how can it be implemented? Let's say the menu begins with different categories, the user clicks on a category and the menu shows the elements inside that category, leading the selected category to the top of the menu, displaying the sub categories underneath. Also when the top category is clicked, go back to the previous column.

[image]

Comment: It has been a while, but I used a custom directive that allowed me to configure how many buttons were in the list, and hotswap the icon, text, and url for them. Buttons could also swap out configurations, which allowed a button to redraw the sidebar with a different set of buttons. I can't remember much more than that general idea, but I hope it gets you thinking in the right direction.